# Async / Await Pattern. How to pass a await-able method to another method

Tags: c#, async-await

In my application I need to call a method before all the API request. If a specific condition met then I need to execute set of statements in that method.

In order to generalize this I created a helper class something like this.

```
public class CertificateValidator {
readonly IDependencyService _serviceLocator;
public CertificateValidator(IDependencyService serviceLocator) {
    _serviceLocator = serviceLocator;
}

public async Task <T> TryExecuteWithCertificateValidationAsync <T> (Task <T> operation) {
    var service = _serviceLocator.Get <IDeviceService> ();
    if (service.CertificateValidationRequired()) {
        // My Code.
    }
    T actualResult = await operation;
    return actualResult;
}
```

}

And In my viewmodel I have done something like this.

```
 public CertificateValidator ValidateCertificate => new CertificateValidator(_serviceLocator);

var response = await ValidateCertificate
                            .TryExecuteWithCertificateValidationAsync(MyMethodAsync());

private async Task<RequestResult<Response>> MyMethodAsync()
{
     // Some code
}
```

But when I implement like this the execution flow is

- First MyMethodAsync() will be called.
- And when it reaches the `await` method it the executes the
  **TryExecuteWithCertificateValidationAsync** method and runs the remaining code there.
- And then when it reaches  `T actualResult = await operation; return
  actualResult;` the control go back to MyMethodAsync() - await statement.

And my doubt here is,

I need to execute the **TryExecuteWithCertificateValidationAsync** completely and then followed by **MyMethodAsync**.

In short as I said early, I need to execute set of code before I call all my API calls. How I can achieve something similar using async an await.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than passing a `Task` pass a function:

```
public async Task<T> TryExecuteWithCertificateValidationAsync<T>(Func<Task<T>> operation)
{
    var service = _serviceLocator.Get<IDeviceService>();
    if (service.CertificateValidationRequired())
    {
        // My Code.
    }
    T actualResult = await operation();
    return actualResult;
}

var response = await ValidateCertificate
    .TryExecuteWithCertificateValidationAsync(MyMethodAsync);
```

---

**Update as per comment**

If the method requires arguments, the types need to be prepended as additional generic arguments to `Func`:

```
private async Task<RequestResult<Response>> MyMethodAsync(int i)
{
     // Some code
}

public async Task<T> TryExecuteWithCertificateValidationAsync<T>(Func<int, Task<T>> operation) // Add int as second generic argument
{
    T actualResult = await operation(1); // Can now be called with an integer
    return actualResult;
}
```

Comment: When I change like this I am getting the following error. The type arguments for method 'CertificateValidator.TryExecuteWithCertificateValidationAsync<T>(Func<Task<T>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: private async Task<RequestResult<UserProfile>> InvokeUserProfileAsync(AppConfiguration config) This is the method I am trying to invoke (in our case MyMethodAsync)

Comment: @Sooraj it should definitely be infer-able; see this minimal example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Rd5xZa

Comment: One last doubt, if i want to pass some parameter to MyMethodAsync() how i can change this? private static async Task<RequestResult<Response>> MyMethodAsync(int i).

Comment: Sorry for this silly doubts. Since I am new to this enviorment

Comment: Thanks for helping me.. :)

Comment: I believe it cannot be considered as a generic solution @Sooraj, as per the discussion you need to execute this method prior to all the API calls.
Suppose if your different API calling methods contains different arguments how you generalise this? This solution can be used only with method without parameters. I think the best option is using Task.ContinueWith. But generalising part I am not sure.

Comment: @Johnathan Barclay I tried to execute your updated answer and which is not working as you explained.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/xz65KU

Comment: That again not a best solution.

Comment: @StezPet apologies, the generic arguments should be the other way round; arguments first, return type second: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6CtvQY.